# How to improve performance of JmsListener? CPU utilization is low

Tags: java, spring-jms

I need some help on increasing the performance of our JMS listeners. I have below set of configuration in my application:

- Number of `JmsListeners`: 6
- Concurrency per listener: 24-72

Also I am using `DefaultMessageListenerContainerFactory`.

My server has 8 cores with 32 GB RAM. This is running just my application.

I am publishing 1M each on each queue so my all listeners are occupied.

During the peak test I have seen my CPU utilization is between 45-50% only. Does that mean I can increase the concurrency? I already did best possible optimization in code. Any more suggestion on improving the performance?

Comment: It depends on what the bottleneck is; could be a downstream problem (e.g. DB) increasing concurrency might, or might not help. You need to profile the application (e.g. YourKit) to determine what the bottleneck is.

Comment: The performance here is also going to depend (perhaps greatly) on the JMS implementation you're using. A poorly implemented JMS broker or client could be subject to long blocking waits which no amount of concurrency would accelerate. What you're asking here is tantamount to asking, "How long is a piece of string?" To echo Gary, the answer is, "It depends."